# Dwarf Fortress starter pack - start DFHack

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I would like to try the Stonesense overlay option. I started with downloading the perdrixerrant's Dwarf fortress starter pack that already contains it and trying to launch it from there.

Unfortunately a couple of hours of searching through menus, options, files, googling and reading around led me to believe that the only way for doing it would be through the DFHack console that should normally launch in parallel at the same time as the game.

Unfortunately in my case it doesn't start on it's own and I can't find a way to start it.

Any help with doing it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The starter's pack was downloaded from http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=7622 (linked from the bay12 forum post describing the Stonesense overlay add) and the file is the 40_06 r1 version.

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the starter pack you used?

Comment: Has DFhack been updated for the newest version already? You really need to tell which version of dwarf fortress and which version of DFhack you are using. There has recently been an update, and not all tools are up to date. (And humungus is right, please provide links).

Comment: please see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I ran into the same issue as you.  It's non-obvious how to get it working.  Here's what you do:

- Press Ctrl-Shift-P.  This will open a console window at the top.
- Type `stonesense overlay`.  Stonesense will load in the background, and then replace your normal view with Stonesense's.

If you close the Stonesense window, it will revert back to the normal look, so you'll need to keep it running in the background.

It's not so useful for the ground z-levels, due to there being so much going on.  It can be used, but it's more difficult than just the digging areas.